# Keep url after redirect with wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to redirect to a url from another url I mean, I have an url http://www.domainA/Auth/Login and I want to redirect to http://www.domainB/Auth/Login but Keeping on browser http://www.domainA/Auth/Login . I'm working with WordPress and I get the first step with a plugin but I don't get the second step about keeping the old url. How can I do that?.

Thanks for your support

Comment: That is not possible using a mere redirect, you would need to proxy the requests through your server.

Comment: You are probably looking for **mod-proxy** . Google " mod proxy for more info about the directive.

Comment: "I get the first step with a plugin but I don't get the second step" - If you need the "second step" then you are going to have to redo the first step (it's not a "redirect" that you require). You'll need to "proxy" the request, as mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

You can not redirect URL **without** changing adress bar.

You can iframe DomainB in domainA. With this approach you can get what you want.

*Sample code* of http://www.domainA/Auth/Login/index.html :

```
<iframe src="http://www.domainB/Auth/Login" style="position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; width:100%; height:100%; border:none; margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; z-index:999999;">
    Your browser doesn't support iframes
</iframe>
```